# Many errors in solution build after target platform update in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, sdk, windows-embedded-compact

I have a solution in Visual Studio that works with a specific target platform.
I'm trying to replace the target platform, so I installed an appropriate SDK and added the new platform through the configuration manager.
When I choose the new platform as the target platform and try to build the solution, I get a lot of errors and the build does not work.
what could be the problem?
Maybe because the SDK of the first platform was built for WINCE6 and the new SDK was built for WINCE7?
Or is it something else in terms of configuration?

[image]

Comment: did you try a full, clean and complete rebuild ?

Comment: Don't look at the Error List tab, look at the Output tab because it gives the errors in the order that they occur. Obviously most of the errors you are seeing are simply the consequence of earlier errors. Look at the Output tab to find the first error. Most likely it will be the inaability to find some header file.